# Hibernate JPA Generate id

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I want that the primary key "puid" gets automatically generated. However I the puid still is always 0. I tried different GeneratedValue variants (Sequence, Identity and Auto) but the result is the same.

This is my code:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long puid;
```

Does anyone have an idea how to fix that?

Comment: It is recommended to use nullable types such as `Long` for IDs.

Comment: Is the entity you are checking the value on already persisted? The auto generation of the ID is handled by the database, so as long as no saving to the actual DB took place the value will still be the default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `puid` has default value 0, when an object is just created.
2. Hibernate thinks that you set `puid` value manually, Hibernate doesn't change it.
   Just change `long` to `Long` to have `null` initial value.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long puid;
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution only problem is know when I am using that I get a unique constraint error

Comment: @user15980267 Better to create a new question with error stack trace and example of the entity.

Answer (score 2):

Use Wrapper object which supports null values as well.

Change long to Long